# How to write an excellent question and answer in Islam S.E.?

Tags: discussion, questions

I’m asking this because on **IPS** it different way of writing a good question. Don’t believe me? Here’s the link: [**[How to write a good question]**](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224/13918).

Ok, I want to know how to write an excellent question in **Islam S.E.** Because, I wanna learn fast to write an excellent question.

I’ve been tried to understand on Wikipedia, but isn’t enough. I need an example of what an excellent question look like in this site, so that I may understand. Because, I don’t want to repeat the same mistakes again. I want to write a question that I can get a hundred and something up votes, for that question.

Can anyone please give me an example of how an excellent question look like in **Islam S.E.** ?

My only wish is to get thousands of up votes if it is possible or at least to get hundreds of up votes for each question, just like Community Wiki gets.

It’s only an example of how **Community Wiki** I only wish to get the same as **Community Wiki** gets.

When I tried x3 to edit [*this post*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48340/23833) then, in first when I edited secondly, I got a ban message. And so, I stopped editing. Because, I don’t want to risk myself to get deleted all my posts. I want to know how to write an excellent question and answer, so that I can know how.

**NOTE:** I’m not doing for the sake of getting reputations in this world. I also do for helping others, so that I can make God pleased with me. And also, it feels great to have thousand of up votes and accepts like **Community Wiki** has. hope I’m not asking a stupid question. And I only want to know, so that I can lift that ban message that I get. I can’t edit anymore something because I have no knowledge of how to write an excellent question or to write an excellent answer that can get hundreds of thousands of up votes. I wish I can be a Diamond moderator. And when you’re about to grant me an answer, can you please, make your answer to be 1000% clear? I want the answer to be like, in top to be the title question and in first part to write the specific problem and so on. And also, to give an example of how a excellent question text and answer look likes. You know what I’m to say?

Comment: Your wish -as it actually seems- can only be fulfilled if you lived and saw the day one of your questions got the 100st upvote. For reaching even 5 upvotes you already need an excellent question or one that seems attractive enough for the reader (many of my own question that have 5 or more upvotes don't leave the impression they are better than those for which I have only no or 1 upvote).

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yeah, I know. That’s were is the problem. I don’t know how to make the question to be attractive enough so that I can get up votes just like Community Wiki gets.

Answer (score -2):

Hello new users of **Islam SE.** Today I’m gonna show you how to write an excellent question and answer.

First of all, your gonna need to follow this below. But number one most importantly, **NO** writing short words( e.g. cz, n) and be specific of what you’re trying to say. And also, check and see if someone has asked and has already an answer before you, before you post the question you’re about to do.

**Why isn’t permitted to write words in short?**

Because, if a new English learner wishes to download **Stack Exchange** app, and sees words that is written in short, then probably you’ll get down votes, or worse, you’ll be ignored.

### 1. How to write an excellent question in Islam Stack Exchange?

If one wishes to write an excellent question, one should follow this list which I’m about to list it:

1. Do some researches before posting it.
2. Explain what you’ve already tried to solve your problem.
3. Specify which language and platform you’re using, including version number where relevant.
4. If your question includes code, check if it is formatted correctly.
5. Don’t add a code if it doesn’t compile, and don’t add the exact compiler error.
6. If the program throws an exception, then include the exception, with both message and Stack trace.
7. If your program produces different results( which it means “votes”) to what you expected, edited the question and state what you expect to have, why you expected and the actual results.
8. If your question is related to anything local-specific( language, time zones) have you stayed the relevant information about your system( e.g. your current time zone)?
9. Check your question if it looks reasonable in terms of formatting.
10. Check the spelling and grammar to the best of ability.
11. Have your read the whole question to yourself carefully, to make sure it makes sense and contain enough of information for someone coming to it without any of context that you already know? If the answer to any of these questions is “no” you should take time to fix up your question before posting. I realize this may seem like a lot of effort, but it will help you get useful answer as quick as possible. Don’t forget that you’re basically asking other people to help you out of goodness of their heart- its up to you to do all you can to make that simple as possible.

### 2. How to write an excellent answer?

First of all, if you wanna write an excellent answer, you’ll need to follow this list:

1. Read the question text.
2. Read many times the questions until you 100% understand it.
3. You may answer it, but try to answer in such that it is 100% clear.
4. Add for each claim of yours evidences as God orders: Show your evidence if you’re truthful.
5. Don’t answer in haste.
6. Take time to collect a lot of informations from different of sites and add them as evidences( in case someone asks you “from where you got this idea?”).
7. Correct the your answer before posting to the best of your ability.
8. Add also this “>” in case you wanna add some quotes from Quran.
9. Add also, links to show from where you got that.

And voila! Maybe you’ll get some up votes. And that’s how you can answer excellent.

Hopefully this is good information.

**Good luck!**

**NOTE:** you may notice that I have done plagiarism because I by mistake entered in my laptop, and I forgot to open my telephone for showing you informations. But, don’t pay attention the plagiarism which I made.

Comment: Points 3-8 of "How to write an excellent question" have no relevance to this site, but might be appropriate for questions on stack-overflow.

Comment: @UmH Then, can you please grant me some informations to my question?

Comment: Stop copy-pasting and start using your mind first pick what you need and leave what you don't if you have doubts then drop it and leave others to do if they are able to. Nobody ordered you to answer all questions or ask questions for the sake of this site.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I thought that ok every site, everyone is allowed to answer themselves.

Comment: @AlexA of course one can answer his/her own question, but the comment is meant to point at the results (like this answer).