# Why have I got banned just because of this question?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know this, is because, I’ve been banned just for [**this question?**](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48340/23833) Really?

I don’t see a reason why I have been banned.

**Question:** What’s the main reason that I got banned just for posting a normal and readable question?

It’s really weird. I don’t like anymore to be banned. I need some explanation about this issue. I got banned for nothing.

Comment: The question ban is something we can't revert as it is entirely automatic, try asking from time to time I hope it will be lifted. Avoid asking bad questions. I hope your other [Meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3383/how-to-write-an-excellent-question) will get some good and helpful answers.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yeah, it would be nice if I could ask time to time. Wait, how can I ask there when I’m banned?

Comment: You are banned for the main site ISE not on islam.meta.stackexchange!

Comment: @Medi1Saif But you can ask on Meta Stack Exchange to change something?

Comment: Who is "you" what I mean is question bans are out of the mod's control when they are automatic. I can't tell you much more none has given me a 1000 pages long manual about how to moderate a site all I have is [a theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) and whatever you have access to it too. And I recommend you to use the legal way.

Answer (score 2):

You weren't question-banned "just for this question". You were question-banned because of the 45 questions you posted, the majority of them are downvoted, closed and/or deleted. That ban will remain until your questions improve. The question-ban limits you to asking one question after six months, and the question you're asking about was simply *that one question*: After you asked it you were again prevented from posting any more questions because your ban was still in effect.

As has been [explained to you before](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3157/22), the question-ban will remain until such time as your existing questions — which includes closed and deleted questions — no longer meet the criteria for it. There is no other way.

Comment: Ok but. I need to be given an example of how an excellent question and answer look like, so that I can edit them in such that I can get perhaps 5 up votes.